# How to switch a tab with multiple spaces without the replace() methods?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to get my method to swap a tabs from an input file with x amount of spaces and print to a new file, and all it is doing is reprinting the exact same thing into the output file. However, I can't use the replace() methods.

So far I have for the conversion:

```
public static String expandLine(String line, int numberOfSpaces) {
   String tab = "\t";
   String formattedLine = "";
   String space = spaces(numberOfSpaces);
   for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
      if (line.charAt(i) == tab.charAt(0)) {
         formattedLine += space;
      } else {
         formattedLine += line.charAt(i);
      }
   } 
   return formattedLine;
}
```

Comment: Post your file i/o code as well.

Comment: Assuming that `spaces(numberOfSpaces)` actually returns a number of spaces, the code you posted works fine for me.  You might want to check other parts of your program.

Comment: By the way, you can simply do `if (line.charAt(i) == '\t')` instead of `tab.charAt(0)`.

Comment: Are you sure your program is not working? It might worked and you are misjudging multiple spaces as tab. Can re-verify that.